# Connection to SQL-server gets lost

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Since a few weeks I have a huge Problem in SSMS connecting to tables in a database, stored in **SQL-Server 2008 R2** on Windows 2008 R2 Server. I am in a Network Environment.

Whenever opening a table "`select top 1000 rows`" or editing data the Connection form appears (like you connect after opening SSMS) and the Connection is to be established from scratch. This takes about 4 -5 seconds and is very irritating before the tables opens.

Connecting once to local Server on my machine does not have this behavior.

I assume that this is since an automatic Windows update during night a few weeks ago, but I cannot say when it started the first time.

Before that, I did not have this issue.

Any idea, how I can solve this Problem?

Comment: Let me guess - you  use SQL Server authentication and you forgot to check the `Remember password` checkbox when connecting

Comment: Basic network tests: go into a command prompt (type CMD and run it) and type `PING -T <servername>` and let it run for a while. Any variability or dropped packets?

Comment: Sorry, Forget to mention that I use mixed authentication and I sign in with Windows auth.

Comment: No Nick, there is no dropped packet, I tried it about 10 minutes.

Comment: We "played" around a bit and our Admin (with his credentials) did not have this Problem on my machine, and when he connected on to the Server through SSMS the Server showed the Little green circle with the White arrow, but not when I logged in!! The circle stayed White, meaning "no Connection", although I have local Admin rights. we checked also the "registered Servers" but could not find a difference between the two Logins.